# Div parent div not containing children div

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

```
<div id="page">
  <---some content here -->
  <div id="container">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now, `#page` does not have any formatting in it. It works correctly for `some content`, i mean, when content is bigger, the `#page` has more height also. But, when today i applied `#container` in it, which is positioned `absolute`, and within it there is a `#child` which is positioned `relative`, it seems like `#container` is not within `#page` - that means if `#container` grows, height of `#page` is not changing, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow of the document causing them not to increase the height of their parent if their height increases.

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in
>   the normal flow of elements in the document.  In contrast, an element
>   that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes
>   up no space when placing other elements. **[Full Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)**

Comment: So how can i do it so #container appears within #page, and #child appears in #container?

Comment: That is right, just think about absolutely positioned elements as being on a separate layer. That is why any changes to absolutely positioned div.container do not affect it's parent div.page

Comment: @ojek, I cannot provide you with a solution without further information.  One solution would be to not make container absolute, but I would assume this defeats another goal you have for the markup.  Post your css and a description of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox: I don't really need to position it as absolute. I just need this #container to be higher as #child is higher, and need that #page to be higher as #container goes higher.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox: Okay, i just did it, i turned off all the positioning of #container and #child, it gave me nothing, but then i turned off #child{float:left;} and it worked. But i really need that float: left;

Comment: If you just need the heights of these elements to increase as their children increase simply remove position absolute and it should work.  The only issue I could see is if your using floats within one of the elements, in this case try adding `overflow:auto` to the parent of the float.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox: Yeah, that's exactly the case. How can i keep those floats and still have my heights?

Comment: @ojek you can investigate a clearfix method or try adding `overflow:auto` to the parent of the floated element.  This is why it is important to post the css with the html.  We could have picked this up much more quickly, making both of our lives easier.

Comment: @ojek Glad I could help you with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Kevin's answer revealed the trick of (why is not possible the) autosizing.

For positioninig instead, note that if #container is `absolute`, and you want it to refer to #page, then #page should be `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` , not `static` (the default).

Otherwise, the positioning would be referred to the HTML element / viewport, the visible area of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Set `overflow: auto` (or to any other valid value) on the `container`.

Comment: @AndreaLigios comment gave an idea, but then making the div as overflow:auto made it working! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`.container` is a css CLASS (as indicated by the `.`), e.g. in html it'd be

```
<div class="container">
```

You're using IDs, which in css are

```
#container { .... }
```